# Is there a linux local tool to view, search, add contacts to/from a .vcf file?

Tags: linux, command-line, utilities

I've downloaded my contact list in a .vcf format to my linux machine. I would like to be able to consult it without having to connect to the internet. The search feature is most important. I've got a script with grep and so on but I was hoping someone had already done the work to make things beautiful and readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of console-based tools designed to process vCard files; I know of the following:

- [Rolo](https://github.com/libvc/rolo), a full-screen address-book manager;
- [Khard](https://github.com/scheibler/khard), a console-based CardDAV client (which works fine with locally-stored vCard files);
- [`mutt_vc_query`](https://github.com/libvc/mutt_vc_query), a simple querying tool for vCard files (designed for Mutt, but usable standalone).

Answer (score 4):

Check [vCard Studio](https://app.zdechov.net/vcard-studio/), it has a good GUI:

[image: Screenshot of vCard Studio showing a list of contacts in tabular form]

Packages are available in [a number of formats](https://app.zdechov.net/vcard-studio/#Download) for different platforms, along with source code.